# Is there an easy way to plot and manipulate time duration (hours/minutes/seconds) data in Python? NOT datetime data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I'm working with some video game speedrunning (basically, races where people try to beat a game as fast as they can) data, and I have many different run timings in HH:MM:SS format. I know it's possible to convert to seconds, but I want to keep in this format for the purposes of making the axes on any graphs easy to read.

I have all the data in a data frame already and tried converting the timing data to datetime format, with format = '%H:%M:%S', but it just uses this as the time on 1900-01-01.

```
data=[['Aggy','01:02:32'], ['Kirby','01:04:54'],['Sally','01:06:04']]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Runner','Time'])
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

I thought specifying the format to be just hours/minutes/seconds would strip away any date, but when I print out the header of my dataframe, it says that the time data is now 1900-01-01 01:02:32, as an example. 1:02:32 AM on January 1st, 1900. I want Python to recognize the 1:02:32 as a duration of time, not a datetime format. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Why is that an issue? Just let it be in 1900. You will only use the hour part anyway

Comment: [using `pd.to_timedelta` instead of `pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) might be a simple solution here. Of course if you're converting it to a `datetime` it's going to have both a date and a time; what you want is simply a duration, which is the purpose of the `timedelta` class in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The `format` argument defines the format of the input date, not the format of the resulting datetime object ([reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)).

For your needs you can either use the *H:m:s* part of the datetime, or use the [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html#pandas.to_timedelta)
method.